# Suppose that $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}=1$ , may $f$ be differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Prove or disprove:

Let $f$ be a function that is defined on a neighbourhood of $0$.
Suppose that $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}=1$ , then $f$ is not differentiable at $0$

I somehow think its false but couldn't find a counter example. So I tried proving it and this is my prove of it being true:

let us assume by contradiction, that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. thus:

$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x}=f'\left(0\right)$

Which implies:

$f'\left(0\right)=\underset{x\rightarrow0^+}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x}=\underset{x\rightarrow0^+}{\lim}\underbrace{\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{\left|x\right|}\right]}$

and:

$f'\left(0\right)=\underset{x\rightarrow0^-}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x}=\underset{x\rightarrow0^-}{\lim}{\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)}{-\left|x\right|}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{-\left|x\right|}\right]}=\underset{x\rightarrow0^-}{\lim}-\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{\left|x\right|}\right]=\underbrace{-\underset{x\rightarrow0^+}{\lim}{\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{\left|x\right|}\right]}}$

They must be equal, thus:

$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}{\left[\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}-\frac{f\left(0\right)}{\left|x\right|}\right]}=0$

As we know $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}=1$,
then:

$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(0\right)}{\left|x\right|}=1$

which cant be, because if $f(0)=0$, then the limit is $0$, and
if $f(0)\ne0$, the the lim is $\pm\infty$

Which in both cases, doesn't equal $1$,

Contradiction.

.

.

Was there a problem separating to $0\pm$ and change $x$ to $|x|$ without modifying $f(x)$? Or was there any other problem ?

First post, be gentle.

Thank you!

Comment: Wow, thanks Adam. small world I guess.
I wish he didn't paste it as an img, as I could find it myself.

Comment: The two given conditions have no guarantee about the continuity of $f$.  The limit condition only describe $f$ on a deleted neighborhood of $0$.  The first condition on $f$ only says that $f$ is defined on the whole neighborhood including $0$.  As a result, it's possible that $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Take $f(x)=|x|$. Then $f$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: Downvoted. This doesn't address the question, which is to prove that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Don't downvote him, I did edit the post 1min later because I forgot the "not". its not his fault.

Comment: Fine, I've removed my downvote.